# Qt/C++: Icons not showing up when program is run under windows O.S

Tags: windows, qt

I am using QT 4.7.0. I have created a project in Windows. I am using some icons on buttons, but when I move the .exe file to another Windows machine the icons don't show. If I run the program in the on the development machine, the icons appear.

I created a qrc file and added the icons to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Icons disappear on an other computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193889/icons-disappear-on-an-other-computer)

Answer (score 7):

Probably you are having a plugin issue. QT comes with many plugins and your application can not find them on new target.

Check out <strike>[this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/deployment-windows.html#qt-plugins)</strike> [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/deployment-windows.html#qt-plugins) link. Copy the plugins to new target and use qt.conf method to indicate plugin paths.

Comment: can you post an example here??!

Answer (score 3):

Your code needs to reference the icons in the resource bundle and not the icons with harddisk paths, e.g.

```
QIcon icon(":/resources/icon.ico");
```

and not

```
QIcon icon("resources/icon.ico");
```

Profiling a debug version on the target machine with depends.exe will help you show, whether OrcunC or my guess is correct.

Comment: i try QIcon icon(":/resources/icon.ico"); but no change happened

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. If it is failing then try stepping into the QIcon constructor in the debugger (using the debug version of the Qt libs)

Comment: Do you use simple icon files or something more complex like svg / jpeg?  Did you compile the qrc and did you compile/link the output of the qrc-compilation?

Comment: i know that is a correct way i use this way in more than one project but the problem know is when i move my .exe file to another windows machine icons didn't appears

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to link the image plugin dlls at run time.

copy necessary dlls in the plugins folder from your Qt directory into your deployment directory and load it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString sDir = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();

    a.addLibraryPath(sDir+"/plugins");

    //*********** do your things

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to include all of them.  Just the ones you need.  Look in your Qt source folder - under plugins\imageformats.  There are a bunch of dlls.  You don't need to link with them, they just need to be found at runtime, as this answer is sort of explaining.  So for instance if you are using ico files then you need the qico4.dll.  If you are loading jpegs, then you need qjpeg4.dll.  The above answer tells Qt where to look for plugins if it needs them.

Comment: @Liz Could you please expand on that? I believe I am having a problem with the qico4.dll, see [.ico icons not showing up on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13891591/341970)

Comment: I was about to expand, when I checked you question (that you linked to), and it seems like you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve a problem is [qrs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this page if you can not solve it currently.

Click [Setting the Application Icon on Windows.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/appicon.html)

Comment: just providing a link to the page does not mean it an answer. you can help him by comments also :-)