# Icons disappear on an other computer

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, icons, release

I've created a program with Qt Creator and compiled it with the release mode.
I've added all the necessary DLLs and everything runs fine on my computer.

The problem is that when I start the program from an other computer all the icons that I've included are not displayed, whereas everything looks fine on my computer.

Where can this come from?

Edit: The icons are loaded in a qrc file...

Comment: Are you using absolute paths for the image resources? Are they compiled within your application? How are they loaded?

Comment: If the icons are anything other than the PNG format, you are most likely missing the appropriate plugins. Qt relies on plugins for most of the data formats it supports, which you will have to distribute with your application.

Comment: For some relevant information, have a look at [Windows Deployment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html) or [Mac Deployment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html) Especially with regards to the Qt Plugins.

Comment: @dirkgently The icons are in a resources qrc file so I think they're compiled within my application...

Comment: @Bart all the files are .ico. Where can I find those plugins to distribute? I can't read your documentation because the website are blocked.

Comment: Starting from your Qt directory, there will be a directory `plugins/imageformats`. This will contain a qico4.dll (Assuming you're on Qt 4.x). The easiest test would be to create a folder named `imageformats` in the directory where your executable is located (on the other machine) and copy the relevant DLL into there.

Comment: @Bart: i think you need the plugins folder aswell, so if the file is located in `./plugins/imageformats/*` relative to the executable qt should pick it up

Comment: @smerlin From what I know this is not necessary (Qt will assume the exe directory to be the root plugin directory) but I'm sure the OP will confirm. Thanks for the heads-up if you're right. ;)

Comment: @Bart: i am pretty sure i am, at least it works for me, maybe both work. You should write up an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of Qt's support for file formats relies on plugins. To ensure that your application works as expected when deploying it on non-development machines, you will have to make sure that you have also deployed the relevant plugins. If you haven't, the loading of files (ICO icons in this case) will simply fail silently.

The plugin of importance in this case is qico4.dll (if you're on Windows).

The official Qt documentation contains all the relevant information on [Qt deployment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment.html) for both [Windows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html) and [Mac](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html). Scroll down to the relevant information on Qt plugins.

As a quick solution you could create a directory named `imageformats` as a subdirectory of the folder containing your executable, into which you copy the qico4.dll.

(Note: user [@smerlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231717/smerlin) says this has to be `plugins/imageformats` relative to your executable directory. I seem to recall that my applications did not require the extra `plugins` directory, but I'll update my answer should I find that this is indeed the case).

Comment: I didn't try with just /imageformats but it works with plugins/imageformats.

Comment: Could you try? Just to amuse us (I can't test it here at the moment). :)

Comment: I can't try it because I wiped out my entire project by mistake and on this work computer when you delete something it's instantly crushed without going to the trashcan. So basically it works it's all I can say.

Comment: Okay, I'll see if I can verify tomorrow and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64 the directories `plugins/imageformats/` and `plugins/platforms/` (relative path w.r.t. the executable location) have to be explicitly symlinked to `imageformats/` and `platforms/` for the deployed application to work properly.