# QML - Images don't load in deployed version of application

Tags: qt, qml, qtdeclarative

I wrote a **Qt/QML application** and every thing is OK during compile time and running on my own system. But when I move this software to an another computer none of pictures loads.
for example here is my background picture:

```
    Image{
    id:background;
    source:"qrc:/qml/MobnaPC/images/back.jpg"
}
```

this image loads when I run the executable file ( which is created in release mode ) in my system ( development environment system ) but when I move this file and its associated dlls to another system( without Qt installed) the background image doesn't load.
I also tried relative addressing instead of resource system. but the problem remained. How can I solve this strange behavior?

Comment: Did you deploy the image plugins as well for jpeg support ? If not try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11196360/894321) with qjpeg4.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the Qt plugins that handle JPEG image formats. The simplest way to solve this is to copy the **qjpeg4.dll** into the same working directory as your executable.