# Qt icons from resource file do not display

Tags: qt5, qt-designer

I made a user interface using Qt Designer qith Qt 5.0.1, and I used icons from a resource file. After compiling, the executable runs perfectly fine, and the icons are displayed as expected. However, when I run the programme on a different computer, they mysteriously disappear, and I am not able to get them back.

What can be the reason for this? I thought that the resources where hard-coded in the executable after compilation, but that may be wrong. In any case, I find it very peculiar that wherever I move the executable, it displays the icons on my own computer, but not on another one's.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Icons disappear on an other computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193889/icons-disappear-on-an-other-computer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing some plugins. If you're using Windows and your icons are .ico type files, you need to copy the `qico.dll` file from the imageformats folder located somewhere in your Qt folder (something like `C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\plugins\imageformats`) to a subdir called `imageformats` that you create inside the directory that contains your deployed .exe file.

Comment: Perfect, indeed that did the trick! And I also notices that each file format has its own dll, so my in order to show e.g. my tiff icons, I had to put `qtiff.dll` in that directory.