# Setting QLabel pixmap in Qt creator design view

Tags: c++, qt

I've set the pixmap field of a QLabel to `:/Resources/Logo.jpg` in Qt creator design view. As a result the ui file looks like

```
<widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
<property name="geometry">
 <rect>
  <x>10</x>
  <y>0</y>
  <width>301</width>
  <height>171</height>
 </rect>
</property>
<property name="text">
 <string/>
</property>
<property name="pixmap">
 <pixmap resource="Utility.qrc">:/Resources/Logo.jpg</pixmap>
</property>
</widget>
```

From which the following code is generated

```
label_4 = new QLabel(centralWidget);
label_4->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("label_4"));
label_4->setGeometry(QRect(10, 0, 301, 171));
label_4->setTextFormat(Qt::AutoText);
label_4->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/Resources/Logo.jpg")));
```

And although the pixmap is visible in design view it does not appear when I run the application. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: any errors? have you tried calling `label_4->show();`?

Comment: Yes I have. No effect.

Comment: have you moved the image into the proper folder IE in your debug mode or release mode folders?

Comment: Doesn't help. The Logo is a resource and should be embedded with the executable during compilation.

Comment: You might need `jpg` plugins for that. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061173/qt-icons-from-resource-file-do-not-display/18073627#18073627).

Comment: How might I go about doing this? Is it just a matter of including a lib file?