# Qt: Setting the background image using stylesheets doesn't work with resources

Tags: qt, qt5, qtgui

I'm new to Qt and having some issues!  Using QtCreator, I created a simple window that i'm now trying to set the background image of.

Searching around lead me to believe i should use QT stylesheets and after trying some examples I managed to get a background image working by using:

```
this->setStyleSheet(" background-image: url(C:/test.jpg)");
```

in the constructor of the main image. However this url reference is obviously quite bad, so I tried using resources. My qrc looks like this:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file alias="background.jpg">image2.jpg</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Now trying to set the stylesheet with

```
this->setStyleSheet(" background-image: url(:/images/image2.jpg)");
```

or

```
this->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/background.jpg)");
```

or any combination of the two will not work!

One wierd thing i did discover is that when I go to the designer window and go to the properties window and set stylesheet of the main window to

```
 background-image: url(:/images/image2.jpg)
```

it actually displays the background image in the designer preview! but as soon as I go to launch the application the background image is gone!

Can anyone explain why I'm having these problems? Thanks!

Comment: This could be a plugin issue. You can try changing your image from `.jpg` format to `.png` format and see if that works. Also [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061173/qt-icons-from-resource-file-do-not-display/18073627#18073627).

Comment: Try `:/images/background.jpg`.

Comment: I've tried both and neither work :( EDIT: and i don't have any plugins installed!

Comment: Try url(qrc:/images/background.png)

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld adding qrc did not help. There has however been a wierd change now. Setting stylesheet background-image: url(:/images/image2.jpg) in the designer now works when i launch the application, but no longer shows in preview. But trying to add it from code like this->setStyleSheet(" background-image: url(:/images/image2.jpg)"); still doesn't work which is what i ultimately want to do

Comment: Can't even replicate adding the stylesheet in the designer (above comment) to make it work now.. :(

Comment: This was never resolved?

Comment: I'm afraid I eventually gave up and moved to other things. Should I delete this?

Comment: I see the exactly the same issue with PyQt5.5.  Anybody knows the solution? I think it's a bug of Qt5.  There is no problem with Qt4.8

Comment: I figured it out that it was caused by the "fusion" style theme. The background image works fine after switching to default theme. That's why it shows correctly in the Qt Designer. Now I temporarily resolved it with subclass the QLineEdit to draw the background image myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you needed to do was add a semicolon inside the quotes.

```
this->setStyleSheet(" background-image: url(C:/test.jpg);");
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. He is trying to use a background image in a stylesheet from **resources**, not direct path.

Answer (score 1):

To use an image in qt, you must add it to a .qrc file.

Comment: That seems to contradict the accepted answer. I'd guess the .qrc would embed the image into the app as a resource? I assume you can still read external files too?

Comment: I should have said the best way is to use an image in qt is to add it to a qrc file because in the accepted answer the path would only work for that machine.