# .ico icons not showing up on Windows

Tags: qt, plugins, icons, toolbar, ico

I followed the [The Qt Resource System](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/resources.html) guide and **the .ico icons appear on Linux.**

The icons are not showing up on Windows when I try to run the applicaton from Qt Creator.

I *suspect* a plugin issue based on [Qt/C++: Icons not showing up when program is run under windows O.S](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6516299/341970) but I failed to figure out what to do from the guide [How to Create Qt Plugins](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/plugins-howto.html).

**Is it a plugin issue or why aren't the icons showing up on Windows?**

**If it is a plugin issue: How do I tell my applicaton where to find the qico.dll?**

---

Details of the environment:

Works on: Kubuntu 12.04 LTS, Qt Creator 2.4.1 and Qt 4.7.4 (64 bit)

Fails on: Windows XP SP2 32 bit,  Qt Creator 2.4.1 and Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)

Everyting is at its default (as installed out of the box), I did not mess with the settings.

**resources.qrc**

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
    <qresource>
        <file>images/spreadsheet.ico</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Also tried with `<qresource prefix="/">`.

From the **applicaton.pro**

```
RESOURCES += \
    resources.qrc

OTHER_FILES += \
    images/spreadsheet.ico
```

In the corresponding **source file**

```
QIcon(":/images/spreadsheet.ico")
```

I also tried as written in [Deploying an Application on Windows](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html)

```
QDir plugins(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/plugins");

qDebug() << "Plugin directory" << plugins.absolutePath() << "found?" << plugins.exists();

app.addLibraryPath(plugins.absolutePath());
```

with the qico.dll in the plugins directory. It application prints that the plugins directory exists but the icons still don't show up.

I repeat: **it works on Linux.**

Comment: By 'not showing up' do you mean they don't appear in your application, or that they are not being generated on disk?

Comment: @IanAtkin They don't appear in my application.

Comment: So, is it possible that they are being generated incorrectly? Windows can get a bit finicky over bit-depth, size in pixels, etc.

Comment: How do you set this icon in your application? On Windows icon should be packed in exe file. Also check if `ico` format is supported by QIcon or try convert to different format like `png`.

Comment: @doc I checked the qrc_resources.cpp file generated by moc. I believe the icons are packed into the exe file: I see the correct paths in comments and large binary data in this generated source file. Converting the icons to a different format is a *workaround* which might work and is my fallback option but I would like to get an answer to my question.

Comment: @IanAtkin Please tell me what to do. I am afraid I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Ali this is crucial. Because if QIcon does not support `ico` format, then you have an answer. You should list supported formats using `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats ()` function and see if `ico` is there on your Windows machine.

Comment: If it's not there you may copy `imageformats` directory from Qt's `plugin` directory into your application folder (where executable is). It should work then.

Comment: @doc OK, I will try. But it would be VERY VERY strange if the Microsoft's .ico format is supported on Linux but not on Windows.

Comment: @doc I tried imageformats as well, didn't work either.

Comment: @Ali First try to list formats. Are you sure that you have plugins in the correct path? `imageformats` should be in application folder (so if your app is in `c:\myapp` you should have `c:\myapp\imageformats` folder not `c:\myapp\plugins\imageformats`) and you don't have to set anything. Also make sure that `qico4.dll` and `qicod4.dll` (if you build in debug mode) are there.

Comment: @doc The answer to your previous question: NO, ico is NOT supported: ("bmp", "pbm", "pgm", "png", "ppm", "xbm", "xpm"). I will check again the imageformats stuff and get back to you.

Comment: @doc OK, the problem was that I put qico4.dll there and not qicod4.dll so it wasn't loaded in debug mode.

Comment: @doc Please write up this discussion for future google visitors, I would like to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For future google visitors: you may read comments under the question, because this is where this answer was born.

So the problem is that `ico` format is not supported by `QIcon` by default and you need a plugin for this. In such cases `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()` function, which lists formats supported by QIcon may be helpful.

In case your format is not supported, you may try to copy `imageformats` folder from Qt's `plugins` directory into directory where your executable resides. If your app lies in `c:\myapp` folder you should have `c:\myapp\imageformats` folder (not `c:\myapp\plugins\imageformats`). Otherwise you have to set paths using `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath`.

Also make sure that `qico4.dll` and `qicod4.dll` (if you build in debug mode) are there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the `QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath`-thing:

You need to make the "**plugins**"-folder available. Not the subfolders!

Here is a way for **Python**/**PySide** users to use the PySide package location. You can also just use your `QtGui.QApplication` instance, which is `app` here, if you have one already:

```
pyside_plugin_path = os.path.join(sys.modules['PySide'].__path__[0], 'plugins')
app.addLibraryPath(pyside_plugin_path)
```

And thanks already to `doc`!