# QApplication::setWindowIcon works on Windows XP, but does not work on Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7, windows-xp, qt5

In a simple Qt application starting like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/qapp/appicon.ico"));
...
```

we set the icon in the second line (this line and icon file in resources is the only difference between my test program and application generated by Qt wizard). This application works perfect on Windows XP, but on Windows 7 we can't see our icon in top-left corner of the window (system shows default icon instead of my appicon.ico).

Configuration of developer's computer:

- Windows XP-SP3,
- Qt 5.1,
- MSVS2010-SP1.

**UPDATE:**

Operating system of developer is Windows XP, so we have temporary answer. When we compiled this application on computer with Windows 7, the problem disappeared (application shows the icon correctly on WinXP and Win7). So now we have to compile releases of this application on Windows 7. But it does not looks like perfect solution.

Do you have any ideas, how to solve this problem better?

Comment: I am not sure, but I would try to replace `*.ico` file with `png` image file first. I suspect, that reading ico files is system (Windows) dependent.

Comment: Thank you for this idea! I'll test it. But I don't understand, how to put in one png image file many sizes (16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128 and 256x256), like it was done for icon file. Do you have ideas how to do it?

Comment: I would use the image with the highest resolution and size. Hm, but why do you need to have 256x256 window icon?

Comment: It is recommendation from Microsoft (to guarantee correct visualization in new systems).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Similar question is [.ico icons not showing up on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891591/ico-icons-not-showing-up-on-windows).
Solution is simple:

- create directory `imageformats` in application dir,
- copy `qico.dll` in it.

Without this plugin QIcon can't read .ico files. So the problem was not in Windows 7 and Windows XP. The problem was in default paths variables on different computers.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is you've got to create a resource file `windows_icon.rc` with the following content:

```
IDI_ICON1               ICON    DISCARDABLE     "images/app-icon-48.ico"
```

and add this line to your app's .pro file:

```
RC_FILE = windows_icon.rc
```

This is the way you set the app icon on Windows (the one that becomes the icon of the exe-file)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, it was done and it works, but icon on exe file is not our problem. We need to put our icon on the title of the window.