# how to set an icon on a Main window and action with QT

Tags: c++, qt

Honestly I do not understand resource files and how to get so that my things can get done, because it was partially explained to me and I'm quite confused where to put icon and how to make it visible on my programs.

```
setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/icon.png"));
```

It doesn't show up or even show a error.

Comment: Are you using Qt Creator? If so, check if in your .pro file you have line like: RESOURCES += sth.qrc. Also check if in .qrc file you have prefix: "/images". If everything is in place try setting alias and use it like that: QIcon(":/alias").

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a resources file named `resources.qrc`:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
  <qresource>
    <file>path/to/icon.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Make sure that `path/to/icon.png` is an actual path, *relative to the directory that contains `resources.qrc`*.

In your `.pro` file, include the resource:

```
TARGET = your_app
TEMPLATE = app
QT += widgets 
RESOURCES += path/to/resources.qrc
```

Again, make sure that `path/to/resources.qrc` exists, *relative to the directory that contains the project file*.

After compiling, your resource will be embedded into your executable. It can be accessed like:

```
setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/path/to/icon.png"));
```

If the icon is not appearing, try this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587359/qapplicationsetwindowicon-works-on-windows-xp-but-does-not-work-on-windows-7) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891591/ico-icons-not-showing-up-on-windows).

Another approach would be to use the [Application Icon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html). This will set the application icon for your application on the desktop and start menus, and also on the top left corner of `QMainWindow`s and `QDialogs`

Comment: imagine if i put the icon directory is in the same directory in which my project is, how will specify the path. directory images can do it like this /images/icon.png?
for the resource file i've found that i can create it by adding it to the project directly by file|new file but how ill specify the resource file if it is added to the current project? for setting the icon application icon i don't have any idea since i'm new in Qt creator

Comment: It is important to use image path with `QIcon` like this: `app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/image.png"));` and NOT image URL like this: `app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("qrc:/image.png"));` notice that image path doesn't have the `qrc` in it

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't it be the simplest to use QtCreator's Designer window? In the lower right corner you can find 3 tabs - click on the most righthand one, then click on the pen:

[image: qt designer resources]

This will open Resources editor:

[image: Qt creator Resources Editor]

Define new resources file (below the left pane), than add a "namespace" (rigth pane) and add your files. You can set aliases for them, so that when you decide to replace your icon with somethin else - you only have to switch the path, as long as alias is kept the same. You can then reference your resources via their alias to set your icon where needed, eg:
`setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/HurBudClientGUI/plug"));`

Also - take your time to read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html and that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-resources.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

There is simper solution:
just go to **properties panel of the main window**, then change the **WindowIcon** property to whatever icon you like.

Answer (score 2):

How to change the window icon in Qt6.

[image]

There is also that one:

```
Form.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('file path'))
```

It works!

Comment: The same is for Qt5 (also for Qt4)