# Define a window icon for a QML application

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm currently reading the QML docs, and I realized that there is no explanation on how to define the app icon.

I tried something, but this doesn't work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/favicon.ico"));

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Can someone enlighten me?
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: There is no portable way, for windows add `win32:RC_ICONS += appicon.ico` to your PRO file.

Comment: Already done. I've also put my icon in the root folder..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set an icon on a Main window and action with QT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284643/how-to-set-an-icon-on-a-main-window-and-action-with-qt)

Comment: No this is diiferent, this is QML app, not C++

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me it only worked when using a PNG instead of an ICO file.
Also you might want to test it with a full path:

```
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("C:/path_to_ico/favicon.png"));
```

Or directly - if it resides in your working dir:

```
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon("favicon.png"));
```

As soon as this works you can try to use a relative path or resource access again :-)

Comment: Using 5.11.2, ico files work for me (at least on Windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

Add the image to `qrc` file. Then give the path starting with `:/`.

```
app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/images/favicon.png"));
```

Qt version: 5.15.2

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QIcon>

QGuiApplication::setWindowIcon(QIcon("your file.png"));
```

Comment: #include  => #include <QIcon>

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**