# How to set window icon Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I need to set window icon. in project folder. there're 2 file, main.cpp, favicon.ico.

i just put icon in relative path. so i can pass directly icon.

But still not show up after compile. what's wrong?

i dont want to use qmake that create pro file.

I tried too create rc file. but same failed to show up.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QIcon>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    QWidget window;
    window.resize(250, 150);
    window.setWindowTitle("Pandora");
    window.setFixedSize(640, 360);
    window.setWindowIcon(QIcon("favicon.ico"));
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Please See this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69219908/9484913) this show you how create qrc and add your icon there and set that URL instead of `"favicon.ico"` another thing that I see , you didn't need `.ico` it accepts png and svg too. I recommend you to use `SVG`

Comment: @Parisa.H.R I need g++ ways, thats answer in qmake build and use QtCreator. i use visual code as my IDE.

Comment: you didn't say this in question :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to setup and add the .ico to your projects .qrc
2. Change your .pro or .cmake to support the qrc

   - May be included by default
3. Change your main.cpp to use the correct syntax for setWindowIcon

Here is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284643/how-to-set-an-icon-on-a-main-window-and-action-with-qt) showing how to setup your QRC and main.cpp to get QIcon() working

Comment: i compile with g++ directly. in linking answer. it use qmake to build project.

Comment: Compiling from the command line can be very tricky for QT Projects. Especially as they grow in complexity. I would reccomend using CMake or QMake (.pro) for all QT projects. ==> These are build systems, not compilers. Both will support GCC/++