# How do I change an MDI sub Window icon?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Look at the following Image:

[image]

I have created the `Sub Window` dynamically.

I'm tried to use  `setWindowIcon` function like the following:

```
mdiWindows->setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.ico"));
```

But does not work well.

Also see the following code (MDI window creation):

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
QTextEdit *TextEdit = new QTextEdit(widget);
TextEdit->setObjectName("myTextEdit");
QMdiSubWindow *mdiWindows = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(widget);
mdiWindows->setGeometry(5, 5, 300, 250);
mdiWindows->setWindowTitle("untitled" + QString::number(ui->mdiArea->subWindowList().count()));
mdiWindows->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
mdiWindows->layout()->addWidget(TextEdit);
mdiWindows->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,
mdiWindows->layout()->setSpacing(
mdiWindows->show();
```

**How to change MDI subWindow icon ?**

Comment: The icon displayed in the MDI child windows can be edited in the properties of the sub-application object used to created the window. "Window icon" property.

Comment: @pes502: I need an example to be compatible with my code, please.

Comment: Have you tried changing the icon with the `setWindowIcon` function?

Comment: @RobbieE: I tried to use `mdiWindows->setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.ico"));`, but does not works fine.

Comment: `setWindowIcon` does what you need. If you cannot get it to work, how about you do some debugging? What does "does not works fine" mean? How does it fail. Does `QIcon("icon.ico")` give you a valid icon?

Comment: @David Heffernan: `how about you do some debugging?` -> there is no debugger in qt creator. `does not works fine mean` -> the icon does not appear on its sub window. `How does it fail` -> my application works fine without any errors. `Does QIcon("icon.ico") give you a valid icon?` -> I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: What is the result of `QIcon("icon.ico")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## What's wrong?

> I'm tried to use `setWindowIcon` function like the following:
>   mdiWindows->setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.ico"));

But you have done wrong, because:

1. You set icon on **mdiWindow itself** rather than it's subWindow.
2. Besides, `.ico` is for **Application icon in Windows**, you should
   just use `.jpg` or `.png` format. The details of default supporting format list can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats).

(If you insist on `.ico` file, there is a workaround. Check: [".ico icons not showing up on Windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891591/ico-icons-not-showing-up-on-windows))

---

## Solution:

Therefore, change this line `mdiWindows->setWindowIcon(QIcon("icon.ico"));`

into:    **`widget->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/myIcon/icon.png"));`**

(Notice that you can do the same on other QWidget derivatives: QMainWindow, QDialog...etc to set their window icon)

In other words, insert the above line into your code:

```
//QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
//QTextEdit *TextEdit = new QTextEdit(widget);
//TextEdit->setObjectName("myTextEdit");
widget->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/myIcon/icon.png")); 
//QMdiSubWindow *mdiWindows = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(widget);
//mdiWindows->setGeometry(5, 5, 300, 250);
//mdiWindows->setWindowTitle("untitled" + QString::number(ui->mdiArea->subWindowList().count()));
//mdiWindows->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
//mdiWindows->layout()->addWidget(TextEdit);
//mdiWindows->layout()->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,
//mdiWindows->layout()->setSpacing(
//mdiWindows->show();
```

[image]

---

## P.S.

Just in case, if you want to set them later, you can call [`QMdiArea::subWindowList()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmdiarea.html#subWindowList) to get the list of mdiWindows then set icons on them separately. For example:

```
mdiWindows->subWindowList().at(1)->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/myIcon/icon.png"));
```

This works the same.

Comment: Where do I put the icon file? also the Icon extension is `ico` not `png` or `jpg`

Comment: Why `.ico` ? That's for application icon in Eindows. You should go normal picture format, like `.png` or `.jpg`.

Comment: ok, but Where do I put the icon file ? are directly or in `.qrc` file.

Comment: If you are not using `.qrc` file, a direct path like `C:/icons/icon.jpg` will work too but I suggest you manage them with a `.qrc` file: to make this work, you can create a new folder in your project folder, and put your icon file there. Then go to your `.qrc` file and `Add` those files to the list. Next, in `.qrc` file, right click on a icon so you can copy the indirect path and paste on wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this accepted answer to work. Don't know if it's a version-specific bug, but I'm using PyQt5,

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
print(f"QT: {QT_VERSION_STR}, PYQT: {PYQT_VERSION_STR}")
# QT: 5.9.6, PYQT: 5.9.2
```

The workaround for me was to set the icon on the `QMdiSubWindow` directly and **not** the widget.

```py
mdiArea = ...
widget = ...
subwindow = mdiArea.addSubWindow(widget)
subwindow.setWindowTitle("My Widget")
myicon = ...
subwindow.setWindowIcon(myicon)  # <-- this line
widget.show()
```

Note, it seems, at least on Windows, that the icon **must** be a `.ico` file, using `.png` did not work, at least for me.